# Project Clarity: Change the default appearance of input and select

Tags: vmware-clarity

I recently came across [Project Clarity](https://clarity.design/) and I love it. I would like to use it for our next project, however our UX lead doesn't like the way input and select fields look with a single line. She wants them to look pretty much like the textarea - with a solid 1px outline and slightly rounded corners. How do I go about changing their default look? I can of course override some CSS attributes. But I wonder if it's the right approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the details about themes for Clarity here https://clarity.design/documentation/themes. Not all aspects of Clarity are easy to theme by simply setting a variable and may require overriding CSS values.

As far as the question about the 'right approach' some things are subjective such as color choices, and other things are intentional like clear focus indicators. If you choose to alter the defaults we have in Clarity, I suggest you do so carefully and ensure they remain accessible for users.

Comment: In addition to the docs Jeremy mentioned, if you are just interested in exploring what and how to make visual changes and you are comfortable with `scss` you can play around with a custom Clarity theme on stackblitz with a custom theme starter: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-custom-theme-v1-0

Comment: Appreciate both responses. Thank you, guys.